# Eclipselink JPA additional criteria values retained and unable to reset the Persistence provider

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

The Question is about Persistence Providers in EclipseLink JPA.

Scenario: 
I have an additional criterion in one of the tables which says

*@AdditionalCriteria("'1' IN :ADMINFLAG or this.column2 IN :VAR2")*

Once a user logs into the application, I need to set ADMINFLAG to 1 to skip setting any value for VAR2 (which will be empty) and access all rows from a table.
Once I fetch the required rows, I reset the ADMINFLAG to zero and set the required values to VAR2, so that the user has access to only allowed rows.

This is how I create the producer

```
  emfProperties.put("VAR2",valuegotfromanotherfunction());
  emfProperties.put("ADMINFLAG",Arrays.asList('0','0','0'));

 EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME,
          emfProperties);
  JPAProducer producer = new JPAProducer(entityManagerFactory, PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, 2000);
  return producer;
```

Problem:  When I try to reset the ADMINFLAG to 0, it doesn't throw any error, but 1 is retained in the ADMINFLAG and as a result the user has access to all the rows. One thing to note is the valuegotfromanotherfunction() uses a managed EntityManagerFactory which sets ADMINFLAG to 1 and VAR2 to empty. This value is retained for "producer" as well.

Is it possible to force reset any parameters set by previous entitymanagers or is it possible to access "persistence" of the application and delete all existing poviders in the context and create a new one every time.?

Any suggestions to effectively implement SKIP additionalcriteria?

Comment: Any ideas? Any directions? any help?